# Do something Automatically

Tags: php

I have an online test and I want to open on 9:00 and close it on 11:00 automatically.
When test is closed students cannot test anymore.
I have no idea about this.. any help?

Comment: Learn about cron job

Comment: You would want to do this server-side. Anything on the client can be altered.

Comment: can you offer any refrence or tutorial?

Comment: Actually you want a solution that works both server and client-side to do this correctly, but having not tried anything this question will get closed as "too vague/broad".

Comment: I told that.. I have no idea!

Comment: Already got the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use cron jobs and PHP script to enable and disable or email your students.

Enhanced Solution:
Store in your DB the starting and closing time of the test you can use it in your cron also. When the test is viewed it should see according to the open and closing time if the test is open or closed.

An easy tutorial on cron jobs http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428